# Have a widget for the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, widgets

Would be awesome if we could get Android home screen widgets for the app.
My preference would be something smallish like a User card (Flair™: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/213798/rhughes/flair ) which shows one chosen profile or an accumulation of all your profiles. To make it useful, it would be cool to expand it with a notification counter or a 'reputation delta' like the stock exchange (see what I did there?).

Others might also like bigger widgets which show previews of Q&A, but as I don't see myself using that, it's best to let them elaborate on that.
Thanks for consideration! :)

Comment: This has already been suggested, I'd appreciate if you could transfer your suggestions for the widget's contents over to the original question.

Comment: I couldn´t imagine that I was the first one to want this, but I could not find the thread via the mobile app itself. Will add it there.